How to create a loop in jQuery function definition?
I am new to jQuery but have had good results so far.
Now I'm trying to define multiple autocomplete statements associated with various text input fields.
I have manually created these 2, and they work fine:
$( "#fromLocation_1" ).autocomplete({
     source: strLocations
     });
            
$( "#fromLocation_2" ).autocomplete({
     source: strLocations
     });

However, this is not working:
$for(i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
    $( "#toLocation_"+i ).autocomplete({
    source: strLocations
        });}

So, either I'm taking a completely dumb approach or there's some basic error in my code.
All help appreciated!

you can do this:$( "#fromLocation_1,#fromLocation_2" ).autocomplete({source: strLocations      });

what's $for? check the browser developer tools console for errors

Also #fromLocation is not equal to #toLocation

Use a class or other non-unique attribute.

loop way is not recommended at all

To create a loop in a jQuery function definition for setting up multiple autocomplete fields, you can use a standard JavaScript for loop. Your attempt is almost correct, but there are a couple of syntax errors. Here is how you can correctly define the loop
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  $("#toLocation_" + i).autocomplete({
    source: strLocations
  });
}

Explanation:

Syntax of the for loop: Ensure the for loop syntax is correct with proper parentheses and braces.
Variable Declaration: Declare the loop counter i using var, let, or const.
Concatenation of String: Use the + operator to concatenate the string "#toLocation_" with the loop counter i.


This answers the question asked, but as an FYI, incrementing IDs are generally considered an anti-pattern.  $(".location").each(function() { $(this).autocomplete... would apply in a loop, or (as per other answer) apply directly to the whole collection, no need for any looping.

@jayesh https://stackoverflow.com/help/gen-ai-policy

The issue with your loop for the autocomplete functionality seems to be a syntax error. In jQuery, the correct syntax for a for loop does not include a dollar sign ($) before for.
Here is the corrected version of your loop:


for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  $("#toLocation_" + i).autocomplete({
    source: strLocations
  });
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




WOW!! So many great answers and so quickly!  Any of the answers could have been ticked as the "correct" one. Thanks to everyone, it's working perfectly now. Oh for the sake of the $ and a var ;-)

there seems to be a problem with the syntax, try it.
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  $("#toLocation_" + i).autocomplete({
    source: strLocations
  });
}



That code sample seems to be pretty much identical to the code in the other two answers. The other two answers also had supporting information, where this answer has no additional insights.
